# ActiveRecord relation using an array of foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, entity-relationship, foreign-key-relationship

Is that possible to establish a relationship between **Tree** and **Branch** such as:

```
class Tree < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :branches
end

class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tree
end
```

But with an array of foreign keys **branch_ids** stored in Tree? I know it's the opposite of the default process, but I want to do so (just for testing).

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Use the term "relationship". A [relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(database%29) is not what you think it is.

Comment: Thank you for the terminology, I will use this term. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Lichtamberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74264/lichtamberg) mentioned it is a bad schema. Since you said "just for testing",
if branch ids will be a column with comma separated values. You won't be able to establish a relatioship. But you can create an atribute like this

```
class Tree < ActiveRecord::Base
  def branches
      Branch.all(branch_ids.split(','))
  end
  def branches=(branches)
      branch_ids = branches.collect(&:id).join(',')
  end
end
```

But don't do this!!!

Comment: Wowwwww, many thanks! That really looks very nice. But okay, I don't do this... :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify a new model (f.e. branchtree) - hbtm or another has_many :through

Then you could have multiple trees for one branch...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't want that (so it's multiple branches for one tree). I just would like to move the typical foreign key from Branch to Tree. Instead of having a foreign key *tree_id* in Branch, I would like a Tree may contain an array of *branch_ids* foreign key.

Comment: But why? Thats a bad database schema, because its failing some canonical forms..?