# Does Faker gem in RoR has any functions to populate random Foreign keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, tdd, faker

I am using Faker gem in Rails 5 for populating random data in TDD. But, I couldn't find a function in Faker gem to populate foreign keys. Do I need to use any other gem to do that or do I need to use random function? What would be the better way?

Comment: That doesn't make sense - the foreign key is a reference to data in another table, if you generate a random value then how will it match anything?

Comment: No, my question is about 'can faker pick a random id from the given pool of foreign keys'? Is that clear now..??

Comment: https://medium.com/@gdiasdasilva/using-faker-to-seed-data-in-php-while-respecting-foreign-key-restrictions-abad5ac1b013 should help you out. It's PHP but the logic is similair

Comment: You can always use collection of ID's like described here => https://stackoverflow.com/a/4009790/1737811 and then use faker to pick the random one. But in that case, you might just use Random class in order to do so.

Comment: @mutantkeyboard, Thanks. The link helped me out.